# Показать сначала гиф, а затем число

Tags: javascript, css, css-animation

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при переходе на страницу сначала в течение 10 - 15 секунд вопроизводилась гиф анимация, а затем на её месте появилось число. К сожалению, я профан в создании сайтов, поэтому даже не представляю чем это реализуется css или js или ещё что.

Comment: А это число откуда будет браться?

Comment: Число постоянное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const sec = 3; // секунд ожидания (3сек для примера)
const number = 100500; // число для вывода
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('div').textContent = number;
}, sec * 1000);
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.gifer.com/6i30.gif" alt="">
</div>
```

JS код расположите в конце страницы, перед закрывающим тегом `</body>` или , если это проблематично, оберните в такую конструкцию:

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", () => {

});
```

Если родительский элемент изображения неизвестен, то можно отталкиваться от самого изображения:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('img').parentNode.textContent = number;
}, sec * 1000);
```

Как вариант, можно попробовать организовать всё это дело только с помощью CSS, но тут нужно определиться с тем, каким образом скрывать изображение и в каком виде должно появляться число. Схематический пример:

```css
img {
  -webkit-animation: hide-image 0s linear 3s forwards;
  animation: hide-image 0s linear 3s forwards;
}

span {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: show-number 0s linear 3s forwards;
  animation: show-number 0s linear 3s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hide-image {
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
  }
}

@keyframes hide-image {
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes show-number {
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@keyframes show-number {
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
      <img src="https://i.gifer.com/6i30.gif" alt="">
      <span>100500</span>
    </div>
```